# Запись в реестр при помощи бат-файла

Tags: bat, реестр, хеширование

Здравствуйте. Можно ли при помощи бат-файла собрать сведения о системе (например, имя пользователя, количество логических дисков), хэшировать эти сведения при помощи любого алгоритма, а потом добавить полученный хэш в реестр? Если это возможно, то не могли бы дать ссылку по функциям и командам бат-файлов.

Comment: Скорее всего, без дополнительных утилит это сделать не удастся. Из всего перечисленного можно только сделать добавление в реестр. Всё остальное неясно как сделать.

Comment: С помощью батника можно только добавлять и удалять записи в реестре. Здесь обсуждаются бат-команды: http://forum.xakep.ru/m_988737/tm.htm. А на тему поиска можно написать спецпрогу, используя функции работы с реестром.

Comment: а почему именно с помощью bat файла?   

p.s. если все же есть острая необходимость использовать именно пакетные файлы, то cygwin вам сможет помочь в этом. у вас есть возможность загрузить, и использовать на платформе windows очень большой набор бесплатных утилит аналогичных утилитам для платформ *nix. считываете данные можно в .reg файл потом обработать awk/sed, потом какой-то утилитой для того чтоб сгенерировать хеш, записать в .reg файл и обрано записать в реестр.

p.s.s. возможно бесплатные утилиты есть и для windows есть но найти их будет, как минимум, сложнее

Comment: Что поможет - windows support tools and resource kit, powershell, wmi, wsh/vbscript, cygwin, инсталляционные файлы *.inf. Еще можно использовать reg-файлы. Но они неудобные :-(

Answer (score 1):

Безусловно можно,вот для примера:

```
 echo %username% - ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ В СИСТЕМЕ
 diskpart - работа с дисками,в том числе их список
```

Кроме того из батника вы можете вызывать команды WMIC,которые, например,могут выдать список установленного софта.
Cygwin'ом пользоваться не рекомендую,так как его тогда придётся бросать на все компы на которых будете запускать скрипт,да и в большинстве случаев всё можно сделать при помощи стандартных средств Винды.

UPDATE:

кстати попробуйте команду systeminfo,думаю она вам должна понравиться)))

Comment: может не все знают но большинство утилит поставляемых с cygwin это exe файлы. в худшем случае вам просто придется переносить бат-файл вместе с несколькими утилитами.

p.s. с трудом укладывается в воображении как с помощью "стандартных средств Винды" сгенерировать хэш

Comment: А dll? Еще придется таскать цигвиновские библиотеки за собой.

Comment: Понятно,что cygwin перенести не проблема,но зачем?По крайней мере для сбора инфы о системе он не даст преимуществ)<br>
По поводу генерация хеша:<br>
-во первых мною было употреблено словосочетание "в большинстве случаев"
<br>
-во вторых можно посчитать хеш стандартными средствами Винды,геморно, но можно)